# Batch save multiple rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, batch

So I am trying to batch save 100's of styled rasters. I have managed to save a single raster in the python console using the following code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

extent = layer.extent()
width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
renderer = layer.renderer()
provider=layer.dataProvider()
crs = layer.crs().toWkt()

pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
pipe.set(provider.clone())
pipe.set(renderer.clone())

file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter('e:/Data/output.tif')

file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                        width,
                        height,
                        extent,
                        layer.crs())
```

What do I need to add so I can save all the rasters currently open in QGIS?

Comment: I found this question when looking for a way to batch save rasters so that I could use the "VRT" option to cut multiple rasters into tiles, and it took a while before I found a solution, but this did work: https://howtoinqgis.wordpress.com/2016/12/17/how-to-split-a-raster-in-several-tiles-using-qgis-or-python-gdal/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this code snipped you would get all layers in your current project:

```
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
# for testing 
for name, layer in layers.iteritems():
     print name, layer.type()
```

I assume your code is correct and that you only have your rasters you want to save loaded. so you would do something like this:

```
layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
for  layer in layers:
   extent = layer.extent()
   width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
   renderer = layer.renderer()
   provider=layer.dataProvider()
   crs = layer.crs().toWkt() 
   pipe.set(provider.clone())
   pipe.set(renderer.clone())

   file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter('e:/Data/%s.tif' %name)

   file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                        width,
                        height,
                        extent,
                        layer.crs())
```

Answer (score 5):

Thank you, your code worked! I had to just make a minor change as %name didn't work for me. Here is code that worked for me for anybody else having the same problem:

```
myDir = 'e:/Data/'
layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
for layer in layers:
   extent = layer.extent()
   width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
   renderer = layer.renderer()
   provider=layer.dataProvider()
   crs = layer.crs().toWkt() 
   pipe.set(provider.clone())
   pipe.set(renderer.clone())
   file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(myDir + layer.name() + ".tif")
   file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                           width,
                           height,
                           extent,
                           layer.crs())
```

Comment: Is there any way to modify this Python to save DEM files? I can save my raster files but when i do it creates the new raster with 4 bands taking the colours from the pixel rather than taking the elevation data from Band 1 as i would like.

Comment: @DavidLaverty you can solve that just removing the line "pipe.set(renderer.clone())"

Comment: In QGIS 3.16.3 the code exports the rasters but it does but without styling/rendering information. Any Idea why that happens? Also, is there a way to add the build pyramids parameter?